# i need a script to check if a value is between 2.5 and 4 and to send mail to xyz@gmail if value is greater than 4 send mail to zyx@gmail

Tags: shell, if-statement, sendmail, floating

I need a shell script to check if a value is between `2.5` and `4` and to send mail to `xyz@gmail` if value is greater than `4` send mail to `zyx@gmail`.

I did tried the following but getting error.

> test_chk: line 5: [: 1.5: integer expression expected

```
if [ "$val" -ge 2.5 -a "$val" -le 4 ]; then
#if ((1.5<=$val && $val<=3))
#then
    echo "   $val" is abnormal| mailx -s "  test " xyz@gmal
fi
```

tried...

```
key1="12.3"
result="12.2"

if (( $result <= $key1 ))
then
    # some code here
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compare floating point values. In this case, you have two choices:

1. Use a shell with Floating Point arithmetic builtin. Zsh does; maybe there are other shells, but I don't know all of them well enough. In Zsh, it would be

   if (( 1.5 <= val && val > 3 ))
2. Use an external tool for the caluclation. `bc` is often used for this purpose, but you can of course use any other available programming language as well (Perl, Ruby, Python, Tcl, ....)